# Avoid duplication of ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some functions that are using ActiveRecord to persist some data.

```
def create_location(user_location)
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
    loc = Location.new(user_location.attrs)
    loc.save!
  end
end
```

How can I avoid duplication of code?

Because now on each method I'll have to wrap everything inside `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection`.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: how can I avoid duplication?

Comment: have you considered a way to move your duplicated code into a helper function/method? which accepts a block as argument?